# Populate and Aggregate MongoDB documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently working with mongoose ODM and MongoDB. Currently, I have faced a tiny issue that I can't seem to get going. So I have a User collection like so:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 posts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}],
 createdAt: Date,
 updatedAt: Date
})
```

and a `Post` collection like so:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
 text: String,
 user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
 createdAt: Date,
 updatedAt: Date
})
```

The user collection has a `posts` field embedded in it that is an array of the user posts. A typical example of what it looks like is given below:

```
{
 _id: 56we389iopks,
 name: John,
 posts: ['6748ufhsgshsklop...', '5e43tiodo...']
}
```

A user has an array of posts, I find the user by their respective ID and populate the posts array.

**AIM**

I want to be able to fetch a user by their ID and get all posts, which are sorted with the newest and oldest post. I know mongoose has an `aggregate` method, but I don't know how to go about this. Thank you, any help will be appreciated.

Example of expected output document:

```
const user = {
_id: 5e34647489930hhff494,
name: John,
posts: [
 {
  text: 'aloha',
  createdAt: 2021-08-30 // newest post
  updatedAt: 2021-08-30
 },
 {
  text: 'heyyy',
  createdAt: 2021-02-14 // oldest post
  updatedAt: 2021-02-14
 },
 ]
}
```

Comment: Add schema Model of Posts to your question, as well as example of Post document and the expected result.

Comment: You can use the aggregate `$lookup` stage to 'join'the two collections by post id field. Following which you can do the _sort_ on the array of posts.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [#Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population) from Mongoose that can help you out. 
Let's try the following

1. Let's retrieve posts by User

   ```
   const postsByUser = await User
      .find({ _id: '...' })
      .populate('posts');

   console.log('postsByUser', postsByUser);
   ```
2. Once we're able to retrieve the posts, let's improve it ordering them by the `createdAt`

   ```
   const postsByUserOrdered = await User
      .find({ _id: '...' })
      .populate({
        path: 'posts',
        options: { sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } }
      })
      .exec();

   console.log('postsByUserOrdered', postsByUserOrdered);
   ```